# RESTful, web-facing service with SNI (Server Name Indication)

Tags: apache, rest, spring-mvc, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a Spring MVC application that receives a URL CallBack from another application through HTTP POST Method that also will send the SNI ((Server Name Indication) for SSL/TLS connections), so I have to implement a RESTful web-facing service in my Spring application. 
Since I will always receives the URL CallBack from the same server I want to refuse all the request from the others servers. Where is better to do this check about the server name ? in the level of the Spring MVC application or there is a way to do it configuring the Apache Web Server ??

I have a @Controller endpoint that accepts a POST request, like this
http://myserver/MyApp/api/registerUser?userId=E506&lat=41&lng=7&rssi=-127&data=3428102231

but this request will come always from the server 111.222.333.444, So I want to accept only the request from that server not anyone else (let's say potencial hackers)

Comment: Not sure I am totally following... 

You  have a Spring Application running on Apache over SSL/TLS. You have an `@Controller` endpoint that accepts a POST request such that body of the request contains the URL to be used to make a callback to (e.g. webhook).

Are you stating that the inbound REQUEST to your controller endpoint will always originate from Server X or that you expect all the callback urls to have a destination of Server X? In either case i'm not sure SNI is the solution, but may be able to provide a better suggestion once the answer is known

Comment: Would the ```@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://111.222.333.444")``` be helpful? It may only allow the server 111.222.333.444 sending request to your annotated endpoint.

Comment: The [Origin header](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-03.html)  `is added by the user agent to describe the security contexts that caused the user agent to initiate an HTTP request. HTTP servers can use the Origin header to mitigate against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) vulnerabilities.` [@CrossOrigin](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html) is not appropriate for the OP scenario. I think, it's better to control the access from the gateway http server (in this case apache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Spring application is behind an apache web server, acting as a [gateway (a.k.a. reverse proxy)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse), you can use the following apache configuration to restrict the access:

```
<Location "/url/of/the/webservice">
    Require ip 111.222.333.444
</Location>
```

From the documentation :

> The [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by URL.
>
> This [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive tests whether an authenticated user is authorized according to a particular authorization provider and the **specified restrictions**.